# Named template with mode not outputting expected node data

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have the following Input, Transform and Output XML. The Output XML is not what I am expecting. I am attempting to use the mode attribute in my templates to separate my processing into two steps. Step1 filters the Input XML and Step2 processes specific nodes in what I am hoping is the filtered Input XML. My Step2 templates simply output what they receive so I am expecting to see the full description of the nodes selected for each template. The Output XML contains only the top-level node labels (Patient,Encounters,Diagnoses) and only the text of the node itself.

I have the following XSLT fiddle at [My XSLT fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTKZ/19) that shows my issue, I hope clearly.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Container>
    <Patient>
      <BirthTime>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</BirthTime>
    </Patient>
    <Encounters>
      <Encounter>
        <EncounterNumber>1</EncounterNumber>
        <FromTime>2021-04-01T00:00:00Z</FromTime>
      </Encounter>
      <Encounter>
        <EncounterNumber>2</EncounterNumber>
        <FromTime>2021-03-01T00:00:00Z</FromTime>
      </Encounter>
    </Encounters>
    <Diagnoses>
      <Diagnosis>
        <EncounterNumber>1</EncounterNumber>
      </Diagnosis>
      <Diagnosis>
        <EncounterNumber>2</EncounterNumber>
      </Diagnosis>
    </Diagnoses>
  </Container>
</root>
```

Transform XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="encounterNumbers">
    <EncounterNumber>2</EncounterNumber>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- START PROCESSING -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- STEP1 TEMPLATES -->
  <xsl:template name="filterSDA" mode="step1" match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:variable name="filteredSDA">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$filteredSDA" mode="step2"/>

  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="//Encounters/Encounter[not(EncounterNumber = $encounterNumbers/EncounterNumber)]" mode="step1"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Diagnoses/Diagnosis[not(EncounterNumber = $encounterNumbers/EncounterNumber)]"  mode="step1"/>

  <!-- STEP2 TEMPLATES -->
  <xsl:template name="demographics" mode="step2" match="Patient">

    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="clinical" mode="step2" match="Encounters|Diagnoses">

    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patient>
      2001-01-01T00:00:00Z
    </Patient>
<Encounters>
      
      
        2
        2021-03-01T00:00:00Z
      
      
    </Encounters>
<Diagnoses>
      
      
        2
      
    </Diagnoses>
```

Comment: Named templates would need to be called by `xsl:call-template`, if the `name` is supposed to have any meaning. Modes are usually used with `xsl:apply-templates`, not with `xsl:call-template`. It is not clear what your first step is meant to process and creates as the intermediary result and what the second step is supposed to do with the intermediary result and how the final result should look. So perhaps explain that with a verbal description plus samples of the XML.

Comment: If I just add the following two xsl statements my original fiddle works as expected:
  <xsl:mode name="step1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="step2" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things by mixing named templates (which you seem to call nowhere) with matching templates.

Furthermore, if you want a two phase processing with two different modes, I would do that at the top level, pushing the result of processing the whole input through the first mode into a variable and then applying the second mode on that variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="encounterNumbers">
    <EncounterNumber>2</EncounterNumber>
    <EncounterNumber>3</EncounterNumber>
    <EncounterNumber>4</EncounterNumber>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:mode name="step1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="step2" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <!-- START PROCESSING -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="step-1-result">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step-1-result/node()" mode="step2"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- mode step1 templates -->
  <xsl:template match="//Encounters/Encounter[not(EncounterNumber = $encounterNumbers/EncounterNumber)]" mode="step1"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Diagnoses/Diagnosis[not(EncounterNumber = $encounterNumbers/EncounterNumber)]"  mode="step1"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTKZ/20

Comment: Martin - Thanks for the comment. Using your structure above it now works! Thx again!

Comment: Martin - one issue I don't understand. I added the following 'step2' template to your fiddle:   <xsl:template name="demographics" mode="step2" match="Patient">
    <Demographics>
      <xsl:copy-of select="./BirthTime"></xsl:copy-of>
    </Demographics>
  </xsl:template>
I now have the Demographics node embedded in the Container node. How do I only output the Demographics node?